# How to get Spinner a Default value as last saved value?Android

Tags: android, view, sharedpreferences, android-spinner, edit

I have Given this to add a spinner in android

Program-

```
Spinner ctype = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s1);
String ct=ctype.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

So at the Spinner Selection I have Given this array

XML--

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/s1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:entries="@array/ct_array"
        android:prompt="@string/ct"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tt1"/>
```

Strings--

```
<string-array name="ct_array">
        <item>ftp://</item>
        <item>http://</item>
        <item>https://</item>
        <item>other</item>
    </string-array>
```

So On selected It Shows **ftp** as Default value..So we can Change them according to the way..

So Here I have a Setting Page In that I have Given 1 `Spinner`,3 `EditText` and with help of Shared prefs I am Saving them...

I have Recently Added a Edit page for Those Shared Prefes...

With the Help of `map.get("xyz")` I am reading previous SharedValues.. For Edit text I have given like This

```
 EditText value1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
 value1.setText(map.get("value1"));
```

So Its Showing Previous Saved Value In the same way i want to Add for Spinner But Its Showing Always FTP can Any one suggest me

I tried with this but It will not work

```
   Spinner conntype = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s1);
   conntype.setSelection(map.get("conntype"));
                      // here it should be **(int)** not **(java.lang.stirng)**
```

Here I am trying to Get the Previous selected value as first like if previous value is `http://` then Show the `http://` if he want to change he can change with spinner But the Default value should be user previous selected one

Any suggestion on this kind please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
 int spinnerPosition = getIndex(conntype, map.get("conntype"));
 conntype.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

Here, getIndex() method:

```
  private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String value){

    for (int i=0;i<spinner.getCount();i++){
       if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals(value)){
         return i;
       }
    }
    return 0 ;
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @tahsinRupam Sir,  Here What is `adapter`?  for `mSpinner` I have Given `conntype` according to my code `Spinner conntype = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s1);
   conntype.setSelection(map.get("conntype"));`